# DateTime display invalid time

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm using C#.

When I'm trying to get the current time with the follow line:

```
var time = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds((dtNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc).ToLocalTime()).TotalMilliseconds);
```

And to check it with

```
var date = new DateTime(time.Ticks);
```

I got invalid year, the year that I'm get is 0048 instead of 2017.

Why its happend?How can i fix it and to know if the `time` contains valid date and if not to fix it? (add the years)

Thanks!

Comment: If you're trying to get the current date and time, why not: `var time = DateTime.Now`? Why the elaborate calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2xf7zzk(v=vs.110).aspx), the `ticks` parameter is not from 1970, it's from the year 1:

> ticks
>   Type: System.Int64
>   A date and time expressed in the number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since **January 1, 0001** at 00:00:00.000 in the Gregorian calendar.

*(my emphasis)*

Comment: Oh ok, So how can i fix that? just to add 1969to years?